# Laravel "foreign key constraint fails"

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, relationship

relationship in Job models

```
public function account()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(EbayAccount::class, 'id', 'account_id');
}
```

relationship in EbayAccount

```
public function jobs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Job::class, 'account_id', 'id');
}
```

main code
//that work

```
        $job = new Job();
        $job->account_id = $acc->id;
        $job->action = 'getOrders';
        $job->days = 30;
        $job->save();
```

//that not work

```
     Job::create([ 
        'account_id' => $acc->id,
        'action' => 'getOrders',
        'days' => 30
    ]);
```

//error 'account_id' foreign key constraint fails

create table Jobs

```
$table->integer('account_id')->unsigned()->index();
$table->foreign('account_id')->references('id')->on('ebay_accounts')->onDelete('cascade');
```

shchema db
[image]

writed

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'account_id','action', 'priority', 'pagination', 'p2', 'p3', 'days','day_start', 'day_end', 'done'
    ];
```

Comment: Give the schema of your tables!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your "Job" Model. Have you set the `$fillable` in your Job Model. Try adding 'account_id, action, days' to the `$fillable` array like this:

```
protected $fillable = ['account_id', 'action', 'days'];
```

This will enable mass assignment to your database for the model.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: alredy writed 
protected $fillable = [
        'account_id','action', 'priority', 'pagination', 'p2', 'p3', 'days','day_start', 'day_end', 'done'
    ];